# Google Chrome script debug feature shows corrupted HTML

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

Occasionally, when I'm debugging with Google Chrome, the script and html page I'm trying to debug shows up with a corrupted string instead of the actual javascript and HTML...
[image: Chrome Debug Corrupted]

If I change the page name (change the case for some of the characters in the page's name), the page will come up correctly.  But if I refresh, the page will return corrupted like above.
[image: Chrome Debug Not Corrupted]

***Clearing the Chrome cache doesn't help.***

I'm using ASP.NET as the backend.  This string does look suspiciously familiar to a View State hash.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a corrupted string - it's a Base64 encoded version of the HTML.  As to why it changes when you change the name of the file - that I'm not sure about - maybe some sort of server setting?
Typically, an encoded string may be presented in order to obfuscate the code.